# Rename Server Name and Team Foundation Server 2010

Tags: tfs, windows-server-2008, vmware, virtual-machine

I have a Win 2008 server with Team Foundation Server 2010 and I simply want to rename the Server to something else (As I am replicating VMs and want unique names for each VM).

I tried to follow these guides:

- [MSDN - How to: Rename an Application-Tier Server for Visual Studio 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252469%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
- [How to: Rename a Data-Tier Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253106%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
- Some other forum links but my SO Link limit is 2

However most of these guides are for TFS 2008 and when I tried the same or equivalent commands, I received multiple issues stating the instance could not be contacted or there was an error with permissions and many other problems. SQL Server works great and so do other apps but TFS just can't deal with a new computer name.

Does anyone know of a straight forward guide for changing a TFS 2010 Server name without causing TFS to stop working? It would be great if there was a guide like the first link but for TFS 2010.

Comment: Is all of your TFS components including SharePoint and SSRS on the same server?

Comment: Yes. SQLS and TFS both the new server.